# Build a live chat connected with windows live messenger

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, instant-messaging, msn-messenger

Live Chat is a very famous tool on websites, and the operators use a special web/windows interface to talk to the clients.

What I want to implement is to specify some email accounts, and when the client click's the live chat and starts typing, his/her instant messages are delivered to the available email account.  My operators can talk back to them as if they are on their friends list.

I don't need to require any login or registration for clients to use this Live Chat.

So are there any ideas about how to implement such a thing?  Are there any good third-party-modules that already do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if what your looking for is possible. To connect to live messenger I believe always requires registration.

If you just want a LiveChat module, this might help http://livechatstarterkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: hmm well, since I don't think that what I want to build is possible right now so at least an ordinary free open sourced chat would be suitable for me right now! .. Thank you =)

Answer (score 5):

Would [MSNP-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/) be suitable? I haven't used it but it talks about provisioned accounts for bots, which is what you are basically doing.

Otherwise you would have to use it and create several Live IDs that are automatically used by the website to talk to your operators. Each user that uses the chat would be temporarily assigned that LiveID so you would have to ensure you had enough IDs to cover active chat users.

Comment: +1 .. Never heard it nor mentioned to me before, I'll try it and let you know if this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at samples for Messenger Connect - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/messengerconnect there is one that shows how to implement chat on web application.

Comment: I think this API aims to help me build an msn like module but It doesn't allow me to have the control to build such a module!

Comment: I tried to answer question you've asked (... with windows live messenger), I guess I don't understand what you actualy need.

Comment: @Alexei - Of course you have seen and used the LiveChat module on many web hosting service providers' websites to talk to operators from this company so they could help with you with some answers or to provide you a customer service .. what the operator uses to talk to you or the customers is mainly a windows application that allows him to receive your instant messages then answer you back .. what I need is to associate the LiveChat with an email and use the Windows Live Messenger as my operator back-end (the messenger replaces the windows application program)

Comment: I'm not sure Messenger fits into cutomer support scenario. If you hardcode accounts on both sides than communication between a user and operator will be replicated to all other users. Or you will require users to sign in with Windows Live account and friend your operator to chat... I'm not sure if there is mode when Messenger supports unique sessions between anonymous users and particular account.  Try to use regular Windows Messenger client to simulate configuration you want and see if you can make it working before switching one side to web interface...

Comment: MJJames suggestion to have pool of accounts may work too (I would recommend reading Windows Live accounts terms of use - http://explore.live.com/microsoft-service-agreement?ref=none&mkt=en-us to see if you'll be violating them by sharing accounts).